# TypeError: len() of unsized object in Python Extreme Learning Machine (ELM) library

Tags: machine-learning, python-3.5

I have installed elm library of python. There is an example provided in this link http://elm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html. The code is:

```
import elm
# download an example dataset from
# https://github.com/acba/elm/tree/develop/tests/data
# load dataset
data = elm.read("iris.data")
# create a classifier
elmk = elm.ELMKernel()
# search for best parameter for this dataset
# define "kfold" cross-validation method, "accuracy" as a objective function
# to be optimized and perform 10 searching steps.
# best parameters will be saved inside 'elmk' object
elmk.search_param(data, cv="kfold", of="accuracy", eval=10)
# split data in training and testing sets
# use 80% of dataset to training and shuffle data before splitting
tr_set, te_set = elm.split_sets(data, training_percent=.8, perm=True)
#train and test
# results are Error objects
tr_result = elmk.train(tr_set)
te_result = elmk.test(te_set)
print(te_result.get_accuracy)
```

When I run the code I am shown this error. It would be great help for me if someone could point out what is causing the problem. I have downloaded the dataset from the given URL provided in the link. My elm package's version is 0.1.1 and python version is 3.5.2. Thanks in advance.
Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\7th semester\machine language\thesis work\python\Applying ELM in iris dataset\elm1.py", line 17, in <module>
    elmk.search_param(data, cv="kfold", of="accuracy", eval=10)
  File "C:\Users\maisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\elm\elmk.py", line 489, in search_param
    param_kernel=param_ranges[1])
  File "C:\Users\maisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\optunity\api.py", line 212, in minimize
    pmap=pmap)
  File "C:\Users\maisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\optunity\api.py", line 245, in optimize
    solution, report = solver.optimize(f, maximize, pmap=pmap)
  File "C:\Users\maisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\optunity\solvers\CMAES.py", line 139, in optimize
    sigma=self.sigma)
  File "C:\Users\maisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\deap\cma.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.dim = len(self.centroid)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: Please read the rules. You need to add your code for questions requiring help with debugging.

Comment: @svgrafov thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have corrected my post.